# Convert Realm objects to non-third-party objects in a lazy way: Results<Item> to [Item]

Tags: swift, realm, lazy-initialization

I'm trying to map Realm Persisted Objects to another Type for **separation of concerns**.

I have something like a protocol repository retrieving an array of items: `[Item]`

I've one implementation of this repository using Realm, so I'm trying to convert a `Results<PersistedItem>` to `[Item]`

`Results<PersistedItem>` is lazy by default when you use it directly in a view but then your whole app is dependent on Realm as you need to import Realm in every views.

I've tried this [LazyList](https://github.com/nalexn/clean-architecture-swiftui/blob/master/CountriesSwiftUI/Utilities/LazyList.swift) implementation but every items are returning at once:

```
func items() -> LazyList<Item> {
    let dbItems = realm.objects(PersistedItem.self) // return List<PersistedItem>
    
    return LazyList(count: dbItems.count, useCache: true) { index in
        print(index) // this is printing every index
        return Item(persistedItem: dbItems[index])
    }
}
```

Then I simply access this LazyList in iOS SwiftUI List. This is working with default Realm collection but not with this LazyList implementation.

```
struct TestLazyView: View {
    
    // Working
    //let items: Results<PersistedItems>
    
    // Not Working as it's load every items at init
    let items: LazyList<Items>
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            Text(item.id)
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the approach to convert these items on demand? Thanks!

Comment: The question needs clarity; "Not Working" doesn't really provide us a context of what specifically isn't working. Does it crash? What are the expected results? A big picture question; *why* are you doing this? Realm objects are already lazily loaded so... what's the purpose of making a lazy object.... lazy? Also, - *whole app is dependent on Realm* - right, that's why your app is backed by Realm. Why *not* use it throughout? Is something preventing its use? You can write a LOT of extra code to work around Realm but why not just use its built-in features? Easier to maintain and a LOT less code.

Comment: App is easier to maintain when you have separation of concerns. What if you want to switch DB from realm to another one? You'd need to update every code views while we juste have to switch the repository in my case.

What is not working is written in my example : // this is printing every index

Comment: *App is easier to maintain when you have separation of concerns* - agreed but.... While the essence sounds good on paper, the actual implementation is often a nightmare. Especially if your separation includes code to override the default nature of the database. You'll end up re-factoring and re-thinking the entire structure in many cases. Try migrating from a database like Firebase to Realm, and you'll see - totally different approach, re think everything. We still don't know what is not working; *printing every index* is exactly what that code does. Do you expect something different?

Comment: Firebase is for MVP or prototyping, you will rarely migrate a realm DB for Firebase.
I used realm because entities is faster to implement to start with but if it's not adaptable to clean architecture I'll maybe consider switching to core data.

The code is printing all index in the views while I expect only accessed elements to be printed as List is lazy by default.

Comment: I was using Firebase as an example, but FYI it's not for prototyping and it's one of many tools that can be used for MVP but that's not it's purpose. The point being is a database is selected because of it's functionality and features it provides. Overriding those features or changing your database (can) changes the overall design. For example, Realm is a multi-user Offline first database. Core Data is not a multi-user database at all so that function is gone. Your code accesses all elements `realm.objects(PersistedItem.self)` objects in Realm which is why it prints all of the indexes.

Comment: No it's not, it's returning Results<PersistedItems> object which doesn't print anything until you access the items itself.

It's when I try to convert the object to a custom LazyList that it's print everything and I try to find a solution keeping the lazy access of that object but not depending on a third party.

I already used Firebase a lot in many projects and it's not scaling when you have millions of DAU that's why I said that.

Comment: Let me update my comment and state this; this code `let dbItems = realm.objects(PersistedItem.self)` loads a reference to every PersistedItem stored in Realm. Your question seems to involve a third party library `LazyList` and if that library is not functioning correctly, reaching out to that developer may help with the issue. Also, double check your implementation of LazyList [docs](https://github.com/nalexn/clean-architecture-swiftui/blob/master/CountriesSwiftUI/Utilities/LazyList.swift) - it looks a little different.